# How to display only result in page

Tags: php

I have a big problem. I wrote a simple $_GET system

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    if($_GET['user'] == $row['user_seo']) {

                echo 'user exists';

    }  else {
                    echo 'No users found';
            }

}
```

If user don't exists in table it display 'No users found' otherwise it display No users found user exists No users found. 2 times it display "No users found" but user exists with that seo in database table. Thanks.

database screen http://prntscr.com/2ddqu4

Comment: Please provide examples of your database and an example of how the user data is formed as you are looping through all users. You would be better of doign the GET before and then querying the database with the GET result.

Comment: try echoing $_GET['user'] and $row[user_seo']. Maybe its a problem with capital letters or trim. Besides that, you have big security holes in this code

Comment: stick to the answer of @jeroen. Once you get the hang out of PDO it'll make you're life much easier. That's a thing I can promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping over all your users so you will get multiple messages.

You should add a `WHERE` condition to your query to check only for the required user and switch to PDO or mysqli with prepared statements.

Something like (in [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_seo`=:user';
$db->prepare($query);
$db->execute(array(':user' => $_GET['user']));
// etc.
```

Comment: i agree, scrap the loop and only retrieve the wanted record

Comment: And for the OP's information take a look on why mysql_* functions should not be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: This is good version BUT i started wrote project in mysql. I can't switch right now. Thanks.

Comment: @user3127605 Why not, in the worst-case scenario you can use both at the same time (opening 2 separate database connections...), writing your new queries in PDO. Then you can change the rest when you have the time.

Comment: Can i write some part in code in pdo and some in mysql, and when i have time rewrite mysql to pdo? Thanks

Comment: @user3127605 Yes, as long as you open a db connection for both.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `mysql_fetch_array` with `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Also I would strongly recommend using either `PDO` or `mysqli` and prepared statements

Comment: I started wrote this project in mysql. And mysql_fetch_assoc didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Safely find the user with mysqli:

```
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $connection = mysqli_connect($Host, $Username, $Password) or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($connection, $database) or die(mysqli_error());

    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user);
    if (!is_numeric($user)) {
        $user = "'$user'";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_seo`=$user;";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if ($result) {
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($user) {
            // User found
            // Do something with info like:
            $userName = $user['name'];
        } else {
            // User NOT found
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You better may use an sql like this: 
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_seo='".$_GET['user']."';` And forget about looping all the rows.

**EDIT**: but better use **PDO** or **Mysqli** and prepared statements

Comment: I really don't think he shouldn't do it this way. You're directly passing a GET Parameter to the query, making it an easy target for SQL injection

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat You are right but I was following his approach

Comment: @MillaresRoo No, you are introducing an sql injection hole.

Comment: Yeah. But please include at least basic protection, so that OP won't be copying this directly